# Convert enum value to some labels in SQL Power Wabit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, report, reporting

I have been using Wabit http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/wabit and find it quite powerful...

Can someone explain how can I convert some enum to some real world label?

Like in database I have following for Order Status:

10 - Pending
20 - Processing
30 - Completed
40 - Cancelled

I get the values, like 10,20,30,40 in reports. How can I convert this value to the label as explained for reports and in charts?

Thanks

Comment: how is the column defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is not define on table use CASE When :

```
 declare @OrderStatus as int = 10

 Select Case When @OrderStatus = 10 Then 'Pending'
        When @OrderStatus = 20 Then 'Processing '
        When @OrderStatus = 30 Then 'Completed '
        When @OrderStatus = 40 Then 'Cancelled'
        Else '' End
```

Comment: Did this help you? If so please mark as answer to be as reference for other.